# GPFlow Multiclass classification with vector inputs causes value error on shape mismatch

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpflow, gaussian-process

I am trying to follow the Multiclass classification in GPFlow (using v2.1.3) as described here:

https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/advanced/multiclass_classification.html

The difference with the example is that the *X* vector is 10-dimensional and the number of classes to predict is 5. But there seems to be error in dimensionality when using the inducing variables. I changed the kernel and use dummy data for reproducability, just looking to get this code to run. I put the dimensions of the variables in case that is the issue. Any calculation of loss causes an error like:

```
 ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 10 and 5 for '{{node truediv}} = RealDiv[T=DT_DOUBLE](strided_slice_2, truediv/softplus/forward/IdentityN)' with input shapes: [200,10], [5].
```

It is as if it requires the *Y* results for the inducing variables, but the example on the gpflow site does not require it or it is confusing the length of the *X* input with the number of classes to predict.

I tried expanding the dimension of *Y* as in [gpflow classification implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68419128/gpflow-classification-implementation), but did not help.

Reproducible Code:

```py
import gpflow
from gpflow.utilities import ops, print_summary, set_trainable
from gpflow.config import set_default_float, default_float, set_default_summary_fmt
from gpflow.ci_utils import ci_niter
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

np.random.seed(0)
tf.random.set_seed(123)

num_classes = 5
num_of_data_points = 1000
num_of_functions = num_classes
num_of_independent_vars = 10

data_gp_train = np.random.rand(num_of_data_points, num_of_independent_vars)
data_gp_train_target_hot = np.eye(num_classes)[np.array(random.choices(list(range(num_classes)), k=num_of_data_points))].astype(bool)
data_gp_train_target = np.apply_along_axis(np.argmax, 1, data_gp_train_target_hot)
data_gp_train_target = np.expand_dims(data_gp_train_target, axis=1)


data_gp = ( data_gp_train, data_gp_train_target )

lengthscales = [0.1]*num_classes
variances = [1.0]*num_classes
kernel = gpflow.kernels.Matern32(variance=variances, lengthscales=lengthscales) 

# Robustmax Multiclass Likelihood
invlink = gpflow.likelihoods.RobustMax(num_of_functions)  # Robustmax inverse link function
likelihood = gpflow.likelihoods.MultiClass(num_of_functions, invlink=invlink)  # Multiclass likelihood

inducing_inputs = data_gp_train[::5].copy()  # inducing inputs (20% of obs are inducing)
# inducing_inputs = data_gp_train[:200,:].copy()  # inducing inputs (20% of obs are inducing)
   
m = gpflow.models.SVGP(
    kernel=kernel,
    likelihood=likelihood,
    inducing_variable=inducing_inputs,
    num_latent_gps=num_of_functions,
    whiten=True,
    q_diag=True,
)

set_trainable(m.inducing_variable, False)
print_summary(m)

opt = gpflow.optimizers.Scipy()
opt_logs = opt.minimize(
    m.training_loss_closure(data_gp), m.trainable_variables, options=dict(maxiter=ci_niter(1000))
)
print_summary(m, fmt="notebook")
```

Dimensions:

```
data_gp[0].shape
Out[132]: (1000, 10)

data_gp[1].shape
Out[133]: (1000, 5)

inducing_inputs.shape
Out[134]: (200, 10)
```

The error:

```
 ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 10 and 5 for '{{node truediv}} = RealDiv[T=DT_DOUBLE](strided_slice_2, truediv/softplus/forward/IdentityN)' with input shapes: [200,10], [5].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running your example I get a slightly different bug, but the issue is in how you define lengthscales and variances. You write:

```py
lengthscales = [0.1]*num_classes
variances = [1.0]*num_classes
kernel = gpflow.kernels.Matern32(variance=variances, lengthscales=lengthscales)
```

But the standard kernels require a scalar variance and the lengthscales to be a scalar or to match the number of *features*, so if you replace that code with the following:

```py
lengthscales = [0.1]*num_of_independent_vars
kernel = gpflow.kernels.Matern32(variance=1.0, lengthscales=lengthscales)
```

then it all runs fine.

This would give you a *shared* kernel for each output (class probability) with *independent* lengthscales per input dimension ("ARD").

If you want different kernels for each output (but, for example, isotropic lengthscale), you can achieve this with a `SeparateIndependent` multi-output kernel, see the [multioutput notebook example](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/advanced/multioutput.html#2.-Separate-independent-MOK-and-shared-independent-inducing-variables).

Comment: for reference, I was using gpflow 2.2.1 and tensorflow 2.4.1.

Comment: Yes, I copy&pasted your script & changed the three lines in my answer